# Proving for $u=f(x,y), v=g(x,y)$, $\frac{du}{dx}\frac{dx}{du}+\frac{dv}{dx}\frac{dx}{dv}=1$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

How do you prove:

If u and v are differentiable, 
$$u=f(x,y), v=g(x,y)$$ 
Prove

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}=1$$

I have no idea how to start. Do we have to use the Jacobian determinant?

Comment: See the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1964678/prove-frac-partial-x-y-z-partial-u-v-w-frac-partial-u-v-w-partial?rq=1)

Comment: Are $u$ and $v$ meant to be the same coordinate pair $(x,y)$ ?

Comment: Sorry I left out something crucial. I'll make the edit now.

Comment: u and v are meant to be functions of x and y